# htaccess, rewrite multiple pages to the same page but keep original value somewhere

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have been fiddle farting around with htaccess and RewriteEngine but I can't quite get my head around it...

I'm building a website on which I want users to be able to go to `/portfolio/typography` for example. But I don't want to create seperate pages for each category in this portfolio and thus I want to rewrite (redirect?) all the requests that go to `/portfolio/` to the `index.php` of this directory and load the appropiate projects for this category from there.

Any ideas on how I could do this? I used this to redirect all the requests to `/portfolio/`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/portfolio/$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g?|png|gif) [NC]
RewriteRule .* /portfolio/ [R=302,L]
```

Thanks in advance,
Cas Cornelissen

**EDIT**

Maybe I should note that I have another .htaccess file in the root of my website.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I found the answer to my own question...

Seems like the following is working:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```